# Add ads admob in React-native

Tags: javascript, react-native, admob, expo

I am using expo to debug an application. In debug mode (`expo start`) advertising is correctly displayed

on when I build the application (`expo build: android`) advertising is not displayed

when using the test key, the advertisement works correctly in apk

checked the key. google admob it's active

Do I need to make some settings to display admob ads

I watched the documentation there described only about inserting the code into the program. I use the library expo-ads-admob

```
<View style = {{ width: '100%', alignItems: 'center' }}>
        <AdMobBanner
            bannerSize="fullBanner"
            adUnitID="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111"
            testDeviceID="EMULATOR" />
        <TouchableHighlight onPress={() =>{this.props.navigation.navigate('SearchObjectPage');} style={{
           marginTop: 30,
           width: '90%',
           padding: 10, 
           backgroundColor: '#a1cfed',
         }}>
        <View>
          <View style={{flexDirection:'row'}}>
            <Image source={require('./src/red.png')} style={ styles.button } resizeMode="contain"/><Text style = { styles.text }>{'check'}</Text>
          </View>
        </View>
        </TouchableHighlight>
</View>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For **simulators/emulators** you can use `EMULATOR` for the test device ID.

However, if you create an apk, the divice will not run because it is not an emulator.

Comment: Should I read the device id and insert it there? 
Or should I delete this field altogether?

Comment: Please insert an id for the device.

Comment: Where do you put the `app ID` for production since with expo you don't get access to plist?

Comment: Find out the device information and put the value into the parameter.